# Historical origin of the empty set

Tags: set-theory, ho.history-overview, foundations

The question is in the title:

> Who first claimed the existence / necessity of the empty set ? When did this happen ?

Of course I know that the notation $\emptyset$ goes back to André Weil, and that the first axiom of ZF is that there exists an empty set, but I ask whether this is an older concept.

Comment: The first step towards the invention of the empty set is the invention of zero, which is not yet universally used among mathematicians :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"It can be justifiably argued that Boole had inventented the empty set" [in *The Mathematical Analysis of Logic* (1847)].

[The Empty Set, the Singleton, and the Ordered Pair](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3109881), Akihiro Kanamori (2003).

Comment: And on Aki's website: http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/8.pdf